# Selenium (lista de elementos de uma classe)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Saudações !

Eu quero abrir todos os elementos (não repetidos) de uma classe, cada um em uma nova aba, como faço isso ? Minha tentativa:

```
lista_elementos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-action')
for i in lista_elementos:
    if i not in acessados:
        acessados.append(i)
        i.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
    else:
        break
```

Outra tentativa, porém essa o elemento "i" substitui a aba principal que estou utilizando, e não é isso que me interessa

```
lista_elementos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-action')
    for i in lista_elementos:
        if i not in acessados:
            acessados.append(i)
            i.click()
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acessar o atributo *href* de cada elemento da classe e abrir essa *url* em uma nova aba. Assim:

```
lista_elementos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-action')
for i in lista_elementos:
    if i not in acessados:
        acessados.append(i)
        url = i.get_attribute('href')
        driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"', '_blank')")

    else:
        break
```

E para mudar de aba:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```